# Auto Format code snippets

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing

Is it possible to auto format code so you don't have to go to each line and space 4 times?

For example I know about the `'enter code here'` but that doesn't always work correctly!
It should be something like:

1. Skip 3 lines to start code
   and then
2. Skip 3 lines to end it

or something like that.

Comment: There are several ways to format the code https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189

Comment: @antimalwareprogram have you tried the '<pre> </pre>'? Or the '<code> </code>'